# How to change materialDesign: property in C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I'm trying to change the property `materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndeterminate` via C# code.
I haven't found any property like that in the Button object.

This is the buttons code:

```cs
 <Button x:Name="loginButton" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,100" Width="100"
                    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}"
    materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.Value="-1"
    materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible="True"
    materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndeterminate="false" />
```

I want to set the IsIndeterminate Property to true when it gets clicked.

Answer (score 9):

I don't understand, why i always find it out shortly after i ask it on StackOverflow...
But here's the solution:

```cs
MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.ButtonProgressAssist.SetIsIndeterminate(loginButton, true);
```